# Cannot start bigbluebutton html5. Im try install "npm start" with "meteor npm install" and it does not work

Tags: html, npm, meteor, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to run the Development environment of bigblubutton-html5, however
below is the error message that is generated after running the following command:

```
npm start
```

This is the tutorial that I followed: https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/dev.html

This is the error message:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bbb-html5-client@ start:dev: `ROOT_URL=http://127.0.0.1/html5client NODE_ENV=development meteor`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the bbb-html5-client@ start:dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-30T23_28_17_291Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bbb-html5-client@ start: `if test "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ; then npm run start:prod; else npm run start:dev; fi`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the bbb-html5-client@ start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-30T23_28_17_304Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Kindly open the file /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-30T23_28_17_304Z-debug.log and paste the log

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution

First

```
meteor npm install
```

Then

`export METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true`

Finally

```
npm start
```

These commands solved the problem for me.

If it doesn't work the first time, maybe you need make this steps first.

```
npm cache clean --force

rm -r node_modules

rm -r package-lock.json
```

And try the first commands again.

Comment: hey i am getting a similar problem where i get error when i try to join a meeting via greenlight front-end and html5 client is loaded it just shows a blank screen and i get startup error Cannot read property map of undefined. can you help me out? I have also set up html5 client the way you have cause i need to change some css

Comment: Ho JayD, that error that you mention is most likely something of the greenlight configuration with the other elements of bigbluebutton, it could be many things, if you could show what error you get in the browser console, and together with the output logs of html5 -client to get an idea